# Appointments of candidates

Tags: combinatorics

I got this problem as my homework:

> An English school and a Vernacular school are both under one superintendent. Suppose that there the superintendentship, the four teachership of English and Vernacular school each, are vacant, if there be altogether 11 candidates for the appointments, 3 of whom apply exclusively for the superintendentship and 2 exclusively for the appointment in the English school, the number of ways in which different appointments can be disposed of is:

I solved it as, first appointed 4 for the vernacular school $6_{C_4}$ and then remaining for superintendent and english school $3_{c_1}$ and hence  $6_{C_4}.3_{c_1}=  45$

but the answer is $25920$ ways. Please help me how such large cases are included.

Comment: If $4$ teachers are to be appointed to each of the schools, then your calculation is right. But I cannot tell what is asked for from the wording.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you are to also consider **placement** of the teachers, e.g. to different classes.

Then $45*4!*4! = 25920$ gives you the book answer.

But I must say that this a very badly framed question !